# Xournal: working on 2 documents simultaneously?

Tags: pdf

I want to annotate a pdf in Xournal while at the same time having another Xournal document open to make some calculations. Is that possible?

(Problem: if I open a pdf document on Xournal to annotate it and then click on "File -> New" the annotated document disappears (is closed?) and I have to open it anew.)

Details: Ubuntu 13.10, Unity, Xournal 0.4.7

Answer (score 2):

A click with the middle button of the mouse on the Xournal icon in the launcher bar will open a new Journal.

(Thanks to Denis Auroux for this solution.)